# Sibling window erases other window on update

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a Parent window(derived from CView) which has 3 child windows.
1)Status bar like window.
2)Custom Display window.
3)Custom Dynamic GDI layout window.
All derived from CWnd.

I have created the child windows with WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE .
Out of the three child windows 2 windows are fixed on the Parent window. 
Third window is a dynamic window which gets created and launched for a click event on status bar window. When a Third window is being displayed it is top of the Display window.

Problem :
When my Dynamic GDI layout is launched and displayed as topmost. Any part of the Display window gets updated then corresponding Dynamic windows screen gets erased.
So for a small region of Display window screen update erases my dynamic windows screen .
Dynamic window gets redrawn when i minimize and restore the entire application window.

PLease let me know how i can avoid my topmost displayed window getting erased when the other sibling window below that gets updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have MDI client setup it shouldn't have this problem, or try adding `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` flag.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani  yes i did use this flag in create() api for both child windows

Comment: did you fix this already? can you post some code?